# Are there differences between reviews of closed testing tracks and release in Google Play Console?

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

If my app passes all the reviews in closed testing will it also pass the review when releasing the app publicly?

Is a release review more thorough?

Comment: Strange. Should be a lot of people who know the answer, but nobody cares to share.

Comment: Apparently not :)